# Getting List of POJOs after executing a native query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working with Stored Procedures and Views. I call these using `entityManager.createNativeQuery` . The problem is that `createNativeQuery` method returns a `List<Object[]>` but I would rather like to get `List<PojoName>`. How to achieve this. I am using Hibernate, Spring Data Jpa.

I have heard `SqlResultsetMapping` annotation can achieve this, but I have not found any example to this.

Please help

Comment: Any suggestions any one ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using @Query annotation instead of createNativeQuery method? 
You can annotate method in your repository and use native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM pojo_name p WHERE p.id between ?1 and ?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<PojoName> findByPojos(Long from, Long to);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem withnative query with multiple joins and found this ticket [DATAJPA-223](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-223). Looks like you can't return a type that's not a entity if it's a native query, even using SqlResultsetMapping.